# Database designing with ERD or DFD

Tags: database-design, erd

actually this is a really basic question as i am new to database designing. I am student too, i study chunks of information but not as a whole. Now my purpose is to study or learn whole process. 
thats why i started designing database on my own but i found that that ERD and DFD(Data Flow Model) are necessary to create database from scratch. I viewed a file having different case studies in it. But every thing i viewed was started from direct relational tables. 
I was unable to find such case studies having ERD or DFD in it.

 So my basic question is that, are there case studies with ERD or DFD? Can someone point me to the useful link?
Thanks for your help in advance and down votes are also welcome.

Comment: Well I googled `database case study ERD` and found one on the first hit: http://www.enggjournals.com/ijcse/doc/IJCSE10-02-08-050.pdf

Comment: Generally, I create (or let my tool create) the ERD after I define the tables.  I define the DFD as a check (test) of the tables, to see if the tables support the application properly.

Comment: RbarryYoung, thanks. i have seen it earlier, when i tried to read that  i was lost in it.

Answer (score 0):

ER modeling, as originally devised by Peter Chen, is not a very good model for database design.  What it really excels in is data analysis.  Analyzing your data requirements before you begin designing your database is a really good idea  (although, in the real world, you often have to reiterate because the analysis is never complete).  A good ER model will allow you to connect each value to be stored in the database with a particular subject matter entity or relationship, and with a particular attribute

Converting an ER model into a relational model is not hard. and you generally end up with a design that's at least third normal form without even trying hard.

Where it gets confusing is that a lot of professionals use ER diagrams to depict a relational model rather than an ER model.  Here are the main differences between ER and relational:

In an ER model you don't have foreign keys.  Relationships are identified in the model, but they are not implemented.

In an ER model, you don't have or need junction boxes that are used to implement many-to-many relationships in a relational model.

normalization is not relevant to the ER model.  normalization is a feature of a design, not a feature of data requirements.

In practice, as already said,  a lot of professionals don't really distinguish between ER modeling and relational modeling.  But in the classical three stage approach, you create a conceptual model using ER modeling, a logical model using relational modeling, and a physical model using SQL modeling that's DBMS specific.  The three models address different issues.